# Is there a place that lists SE site privileges for a user?

Tags: feature-request, support

Is there a place on Stack Exchange that lists specific user privileges earned, such as question, answer, flag, vote, comment?

There's already a place to see user-earned badges.

Comment: For all sites, or for a given individual site? As in, a list of what you can do on _every_ site, or (for example) do you just want to see what you can do on, say MSE?

Comment: The help center?

Comment: yes, privileges.  MSE, any SE

Comment: I looked at the question listed as duplicate and don't see an answer to my question.

Comment: It is not explicitly listed for a user because a privilege is directly linked to reputation. If you know someones reputation, you know their privileges. Having a privilege list per user is not useful.

Comment: Thanks. That answered the question.  I can't check a comment as an answered question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Meta.SE, go here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

For SO, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

For any other site, just append "/help/privileges" to the site name.

Comment: Thanks to the comment above I see that you did answer the question.  Thanks.  I did not know that there was a direct relationship between reputation and privilege.